# How do I set iptables so that https://bing.com is blocked, but http://bing.com is not?

Tags: iptables, https

`-A OUTPUT -d bing.com -j DROP` – works: Block bing.com through http and https as well.

So I try to modify it so that only https is blocked:

`-A OUTPUT -d bing.com --dport 443 -j DROP` – but this won’t work, bing.com is allowed through http and https as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Ah, and this is a home computer, I just want to prohibit browsing bing.com through https.

Comment: If you want to block domain names, you need a proxy. iptables doesn’t see the `Host` header. If you block by IP address, you may inadvertently block other stuff as well.

Comment: @DanielB Hrm, so why does `-A OUTPUT -d bing.com -j DROP` work as expected?

Comment: Because DNS responses are cached. It’s simply not reliable this way.

Comment: Bing owns a lot of IP addresses and iptables doesn't do a fresh lookup each time.  You need to block at least 204.79.196.0/23, 204.79.195.0/24 these 2 subnets if not even more than that.  Bing may even attempt to upgrade a non SSL to SSL over port 80.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can’t I block https?](http://superuser.com/questions/1078443/why-can-t-i-block-https)

Comment: @T.J.L. Close, but not exactly a dupe. With this question, issues like the ones outlined by Daniel B and cybernard above would have to be considered. With the other question, no such issues show up.

Answer (score 0):

To block particular sites use the -d option to specify the hostname.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d bing.com -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: Won’t work. I get the following error: `The "nat" table is not intended for filtering, the use of DROP is therefore inhibited.`

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: `-d` specifies the destination, not the host name. The destination can be given as a host name, which is looked up at the time of rule creation, but it isn't stored that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I reeeaaally want to do it this way, the correct command seems to be:

`iptables -I OUTPUT -d bing.com -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP`

My mistake above seems to be that I didn’t precede `--dport 443` with `-p tcp`. That way, I was getting the following error: `unknown option "--dport"`

Of course, comments by @Daniel B and @cybernard they have posted to my question apply.