# Why can’t I block https?

Tags: iptables, https

May I ask why can I not block all https traffic in iptables?

I tried:

```
OUTPUT --dport 443 -j DROP
```

And even:

```
OUTPUT --sport 443 -j DROP
```

None of this works. Https webpages are still perfectly accessible. WHY? What kind of PEBKAC have I managed to subject myself to this time?

Comment: Just an FYI, any website with HSTS (including google) will not be downgraded to HTTP, the request will just fail. Blocking HTTPS will likely annoy many users.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You can block access to all https based sites with iptables using the following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

To block particular sites use the -d option to specify the hostname.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m tcp -p tcp -d www.example.com --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Try this

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: OK but why PREROUTING?

Comment: I mean, I’m doing it on my PC, not on a router.

Comment: Also, why did my rules fail to work?

Comment: Also, sadly, your rule doesn’t work. Instead I am shown this: `The "nat" table is not intended for filtering, the use of DROP is therefore inhibited.`

Comment: I edited my answer, try the 3rd example

Comment: Nm looks like you already figured that out

Answer (score 1):

Finally. Yep, it was a PEBKAC.

The solution is to write: `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP`

The way I was doing it, I was getting error: `unknown option "--dports"`

I didn’t see it, because I wasn’t adding the rule with the `iptables` command, but rather by adding it to a file that was being read by iptables at startup. Silly me.

Comment: Well at least you got it resolved.  Next time, please post any related error messages you see like that.  Seeing that error message would have been a huge red flag.

Comment: How you used the lines in question should have been included in the question.